# Как получить значения с созданного мною с помощью Renderer2 input

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

Не судите строго код, пока что учусь, но не могу понять как получить значение с input, или как ему изначально привязать индификатор, или атрибут [(ngModel)]
HTML:

```
<div class="container" #container>
   <button *ngIf = 'active; else otvet' class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search" (click) = 'search()'>Знайти</button>
  <ng-template #otvet>
    <button id="answer" class="btn btn-outline-success"  (click) = 'answer()'>Ответ</button>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, Renderer2, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ukr',
  templateUrl: './ukr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ukr.component.css']
})
export class UkrComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("container", {read: ElementRef}) private container: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  result: string;
  active: boolean = true;
  schet : number = 0;
  zadaniy: any =  [
    "с1нце",
    "а1куш",
    "бал1т",
    "ва1он",
    "ва1та",
    "с1ово",
    'узв1р',
    "хо1як",
    "те1ст",
    "я1ода"
  ];
  slova_otveta: any = [
  "о",
  "р",
  "е",
  "г",
  "р",
  "л",
  "а",
  "м",
  "к",
  "г"];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }




  zapolnit(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){

      let bykva = this.zadaniy[this.schet][i];

      if(bykva == '1'){
          let dly_otveta = this.renderer.createElement('input');
          this.renderer.addClass(dly_otveta, 'number');
          this.renderer.setAttribute(dly_otveta, 'id', 'symb_otvet');
          this.renderer.setProperty(dly_otveta, '([ngModel]', 'result');
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement, dly_otveta);
          }

      else{
          let div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
          let text = this.renderer.createText(this.zadaniy[this.schet][i]);
          this.renderer.appendChild(div,text);
          this.renderer.addClass(div,'number');
          this.renderer.setAttribute(div,'id', 'symb' + i);
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement,div);
          }
      }
      this.schet++;
  }


  search(){
      this.zapolnit();
      this.active = !this.active;
  }

  answer(){
    console.log(this.result);// вот тут хочу ввывести то что написали в input но не могу понять как 
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let dly_otveta = this.renderer.createElement('input');
```

dly_otveta - это твой input
c у него есть dly_otveta.value